# Unable to cast Omnetpp::cPacket to Inet::Packet

Tags: c++, casting, omnet++, inet

I am trying to send a packet using socket but it's throwing an error.

> invalid conversion from ‘omnetpp::cPacket*’ to ‘inet::Packet*’ [-fpermissive]

My code is as follows:

```
    cPacket *payload = createPacket();
    //Packet* *payload = createPacket();
    payload->setTimestamp();
    emit(sentPkSignal, payload);
    socket.sendTo(payload, destAddr, destPort);
    numSent++;
```

I have tried using check and cast. Im new to C++ as well as OMNET++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `omnetpp::cPacket` and `inet::Packet` is two entirely different thing and you cannot cast or convert one to the other. As you are using INET 4, you MUST create an `inet::Packet` and pass that to the `socket.sendTo()` call.

Check the existing application's code to see how to create inet::Packets. i.e.  https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/v4.1.2/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.cc#L108

Comment: Thank you so much. I just created an inet::Packet instead of an omnetpp::cPacket. With Reference from the UdpBasicApp.
    `std::ostringstream str;
    Packet *payload = new Packet(str.str().c_str());
    payload->setTimestamp();
    L3Address destAddr = chooseDestAddr();
    emit(packetSentSignal, payload);
    socket.sendTo(payload, destAddr, destPort);
    numSent++`